# Determining if two numbers are close in value by defining a function

Tags: python, function

I have to write a function that takes in three parameters and returns True is the first two parameters are close in value to each other (they are within +/- the third parameter.

```
def assert_within_tolerance(num1,num2,close):
num1=float(num1)
num2=float(num2)
while close>=0:
    if num1-num2<=close:
        return True
    elif num2-num1<=close:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This code isn't returning True or False correctly and I'm not sure why

Comment: Ok? And what's wrong with the code you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def compare(n1, n2, delta):
    return abs(n1-n2) <= delta
```

The function returns true iff:
**n1 > n2** :
 n1-n2 <=  delta 

**[OR]** 
**n1 < n2**  :
n1-n2 <= -delta

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(a, b, epsilon): 
    return abs(a - b) <= epsilon
```

Comment: I believe it should be <=